# Conditional probability problem - acceptance to two colleges

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, independence

I'm doing this problem:

```
A student is applying to Harvard and Dartmouth. He estimates that he has
a probability of .5 of being accepted at Dartmouth and .3 of being accepted
at Harvard. He further estimates the probability that he will be accepted by
both is .2. What is the probability that he is accepted by Dartmouth if he is
accepted by Harvard? Is the event “accepted at Harvard” independent of the
event “accepted at Dartmouth”?
```

So I begin with the p(D|H)=p(D and H)/p(H) which I find eerily suspicious because is too easy, so is wrong, but why? First the probabilities do not sum to one p(H)+p(D)≠1. So I'm missing something obvious but what??

Thanks.

Comment: This surely seems like homework. If so, you should add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Why should p(H) + p(D) = 1?

Comment: Tag added, because those are the only 2 options I see, maybe p(no college) is .2??

Comment: P(H) + P(no H) = 1. So does P(D) + P(no D). However, here there are 4 possibilities: H only, D only, H+D, and neither. Those 4 together have to = 1.

Comment: Ha ok I see it, I've forgotten H', ok then I will try something. Thanks.

Comment: Nope I don't get it, can you explain this one to me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11615/discussion-between-pedro-alonso-and-peter-flom)

Comment: I suggest you draw a diagram; draw a region enclosed by a closed curve (like a square or circle) to represent the probability. Draw a line to cut the region more-or-less horizontally to represent the Harvard-offer/no-Harvard-offer case and more-or-less vertically to represent the other dichotomy. Then think about what the various parts of the question mean in terms of the subregions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to draw and use something like the diagram below to lay out the information (write it in the spaces and margins) and then you may be able to see how to do the problem. You would write all of the values on the diagram and from them fill in probabilities for every subregion and colored region(/margin). Then you should have a clearer idea what everything is.

[image: diagram for conditional probability problem]

Since (from his post in chat) the OP has worked the last details out correctly; here's my outline of the answer:

Given the values in the question (in blue), we can infer the other probabilities (in dark red) by subtraction:

[image: diagram with values filled in]

a) The "*probability that he is accepted by Dartmouth if he is
accepted by Harvard*" $= P(D|H) = P(D\cap H)/P(H) = 0.2/0.3 = 2/3$

b) "*Is the event “accepted at Harvard” independent of the
event “accepted at Dartmouth”?*".

The two events are independent if
$P(D\cap H)=P(D)P(H)$; equivalently they are independent if $P(D|H)=P(D)$ (as long as $P(H)$ is not 0).

In the first approach $P(D)P(H)= 0.5\times 0.3 = 0.15 \neq P(D\cap H)=0.2$, while using the second approach, $P(D|H)=2/3\neq P(D)=0.5$, so either way the events are not independent.

Comment: I have done it like that, I get p(H')=0.5, p(H)=0.5, p(D)=0.3, p(D')=0.7, p(D and H)=0.2, p(D and H')=0.1, p(D' and H)=0.3, p(D' and H')=0.4, and p((H)*p(D)=0.15 therefore they are not independent. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite (unless I made an error). Check your answers for p(D and H') and p(D' and H). But you're on the right track.

Comment: Your conclusion about independence is right, and looks like it's for the right reason.

Comment: Well I cant find the mistake, let me go tru this again p(H)=0.5, then p(H')=0.5, p(D)=0.3, p(D')=0.7, correct? Then in the table of the joint probabilities I have subtracted the marginal and the one joint I have like: p(D and H')=p(D)-p(D and H), 0.3-0.2=0.1, correct?

Comment: And summing the 4 entries gives me 1, 0.1+0.4+0.2+0.3=1, so why is this? Can you tell me the mistake it will be better. :)

Comment: p(H) is not 0.5. Reread the question. The 4 possibilities are mutually exclusive and mutually exhaustive; they cover every possibility. So they *must* add to 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11638/discussion-between-pedro-alonso-and-glen-b)